# Testing if a property is set in object returns true, when its not

Tags: javascript

I am using the `in` operator to check if a property is set. I am getting an unexpected result. When a property is not set, for some reason, it still returns true

```
console.log('completion', JSON.stringify(completion), (completion && ('transaction' in completion)));
```

`JSON.stringify(completion)` returns `{"user":3,"survey":"4ydBY0t6","year":2015,"month":9,"id":38,"createdAt":"2015-09-29T08:08:08.000Z","updatedAt":"2015-09-29T08:08:08.000Z"}` but `(completion && ('transaction' in completion))` returns `true` why might that be?

Abit more code around the affected line

```
resp.surveys.forEach(function(survey) {
    var completion = _.find(completions, { survey: survey.id });

    console.log('completion', JSON.stringify(completion), (completion && ('transaction' in completion)));

    // ...
    survey.pointsAwarded = (completion && ('transaction' in completion)) ? completion.transaction.points : 0;
});
```

Comment: maybe `transaction` is available via `completion.__proto__`? have you tried `completion.hasOwnProperty('transaction')`?

Comment: @gefei if transaction is in proto shouldn't stringify also serialize it?

Comment: @x4rf41 here `(completion && ('transaction' in completion))` `completion` is not stringified

Comment: @JiewMeng have you tried using a debugger and go step by step from `var completion = _.find(completions, { survey: survey.id });` and inspect the completion object in the debugger. the debugger will show you everything that is really there. the in operator should work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` only looks at an object's *own enumerable properties*. `in`, on the other hand, looks at whether the property exists on the object (whether enumerable or not) or any of its prototypes. `JSON.stringify` will also leave out properties whose values are `undefined` or functions.

So there are three ways `transaction` can be there but not show up in the JSON:

1. It's not enumerble
2. It's inherited via the prototype chain
3. Its value is `undefined` or a function reference

Here's an example of all three:

```js
var proto = {
  inherited: true
};
var obj = Object.create(proto);
Object.defineProperty(obj, "non-enumerable", {
  value: true
});
obj.function = function() { };
obj.showsUp = true;
document.body.innerHTML =
  "<pre>" +
  "'inherited' in obj? " + ('inherited' in obj) + "\n" +
  "'function' in obj? " + ('function' in obj) + "\n" +
  "'non-enumerable' in obj? " + ('non-enumerable' in obj) + "\n" +
  "JSON: " + JSON.stringify(obj) +
  "</pre>";
```

Comment: Nice and deep Explaination!